# Creation of new page

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have been working on a website and I have created a nav bar and the hero section of my website.
If I click on a certain element(eg. Men,Women,Teens) of the navbar it takes me to a page within the website(i.e. shows inside the website only) a 404 error.
Now I would like to add some content to that page.

But whenever I create a new component within my  components folder(eg. Men.tsx etc.) and try to import it, it does not work.
I am confused on how to create a new page with content for a website using Next.js and TypeScript.
Code for Navbar

```
    "use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Link, ShoppingBag } from "lucide-react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

const links = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/' },
  { name: 'Men', href: '/Men' },
  { name: 'Women', href: '/Women' },
  { name: 'Teens', href: '/Teens' },
];

export default function Navbar() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  return (
    <header className="mb-8 border-b">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between x-auto max-w-2xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:max-w-7xl">
        <a href="/">
          <h1 className="test-2xl md:text-4xl font-bold">Next<span className="text-primary">Commerce</span></h1>
        </a>
        <nav className="hidden gap-12 lg:flex 2xl:ml-16">
          {links.map((link, idx) => (
            <div key={idx}>
              <a
                href={link.href}
                className={
                  pathname === link.href
                    ? "text-lg font-semibold text-primary"
                    : "text-lg font-semibold text-gray-600 transition duration-100 hover:text-primary"
                }
              >
                {link.name}
              </a>
            </div>
          ))}

<Link href="/Men">
  <a className={pathname === '/Men' ? "active" : "Hello"}>Men</a>
</Link>

        </nav>
        <div className="flex divide-x border-r sm:border-l">
          <Button variant={"outline"} className="flex flex-col gapy-y-1.5 h-12 w-12 sm:w-20 sm:h-20 md:h-24 md:w-24 rounded-none">
            <ShoppingBag/>
            <span className="hidden text-xs font-semibold text-gray-500 sm:block">
              Cart
            </span>
          </Button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello @Nishant welcome to stack overflow. firstly check the documentation of next js and try it once for yourself https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing

Comment: Share us your project structure and your code